# How does many-worlds interpretation make measurement unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

Does [many-worlds interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) of QM make the process of measurement (wavefunction collapse) be an unitary transform?
If so, how does it do this?

If we have an "object" qubit in state

$$\left|q_1\right>$$

and a "meter" qubit in state

$$\left|q_2\right>$$

then what is the measurement matrix here?

Since measurement should erase an old state of "meter" qubit, then how can it be unitary?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20014/discussion-on-question-by-dims-how-does-many-worlds-interpretation-make-measurem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measurement is not the same as wavefunction collapse. A measurement is an interaction that produces information about a system that can be copied to multiple other systems. Such an interaction does not copy all of the information in the state of a system, only the information instantiated in some set of orthogonal projectors, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245.

This does not contradict the no-cloning theorem, which prohibits copying the whole content of the information in the state of a system, but does not prohibit copying the specific information cited above.

You ask what the measurement operator for one qubit being measured onto another. If they are being measured in the computation basis $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ then a perfect measurement is represented by controlled not $U = |00\rangle\langle 00|+|01\rangle\langle 01|+|10\rangle\langle 11|+|11\rangle\langle 10|$, which is unitary.

If the measured qubit is sharp in the computation basis and the meter qubit is in $|0\rangle$  then the final state of the measurement qubit is the same as that of the measured qubit.

If the state of the measured qubit is not sharp in the computation basis and the meter qubit is in $|0\rangle$, then we get
$$
(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)|0\rangle \to\alpha|00\rangle+\beta|11\rangle.
$$

The way to interpret this is that there are two versions of each qubit, one in state $|0\rangle$, the other in state $|1\rangle$. As the meter qubit interacts with other systems they too will differentiate into two versions, one for each possible outcome. These different versions of each system don't interact with each other, so you can't see them. Since the resulting versions each act approximately like the universe as described by classical physics they are called universes. This all takes place unitarily. See

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033.

The old state is not erased, rather it was initially prepared in such a way that the measurement gives you the information you want.

Comment: how can a measurement go without collapse and though producing a response that can be copied as many times as we wish? Don't you know the "no-cloning theorem"?

Comment: @Sofia, I suspect he is aware of the no-cloning theorem.  The measurement $(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)|0\rangle \to\alpha|00\rangle+\beta|11\rangle$ does not represent a cloning of the state $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$. A clone is two copies of the state, i.e.  $(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)\otimes|0\rangle \to (\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)\otimes(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)$

Comment: @lionelbrits : no, Lionel, it was another reason that I objected about cloning. He says "A measurement is an interaction that produces information about a system that can be copied to multiple other systems." This is cloning, i.e. creating other systems with the same wave-function. I disagree! The measurement (α|0⟩+β|1⟩)|0⟩→α|00⟩+β|11⟩, I mean, even repeating the measurement many times, will never tell us what are α and β, only what are |α|^2 and |β|^2. We have to change the apparatus in different ways and do measurements, for being able to infer α and β.

Comment: Well, it is only cloning if complete information is copied to multiple other systems. But incomplete information is copied, which is just entanglement. Measurement is the entanglement of the apparatus with the system to be measured.

Comment: @lionelbrits : I have to postpone everything to tomorrow. It will be a very difficult day, very bad weather was announced and I have to travel. So, I have to make preparations. "See" you tomorrow in the afternoon or so.

Comment: @lionelbrits , I see your point but due to your explanation. From alanf's words "information about a system that can be copied to multiple other systems"  I understood that he wants to copy the **whole** state of the examined system, which is impossible. Though, there are some things that don't arrange well, but, see you tomorrow.

Comment: No. Saying that there is information about one system that can be copied to others does not imply that all the information about that system is copied and in fact it is not all copied. The information that is copied is the information instantiated in a particular set of orthogonal projectors.

Comment: @alanf : won't you be so kind to insert this explanation into your answer? Thus, whatever misunderstanding would be avoided.

Comment: I deleted my post about many words because I am sick with this. We can know ***only*** what happens in ***our*** world. If someone believes that the unitarity can be rescued by inventing worlds where we cannot get in, I wish him to enjoy that. The collapse ***cannot*** be rescued by many worlds, but it's of no use to hold this, because who believes in it would invent more and more **ad-hoc** arguments, like kids that want smth. that the parents disagree.

Comment: @Hipnosifl I don't know who is obsessed by the MI. I deleted my answer because I am sick with this. The collapse cannot be solved by many worlds, because it is not known what causes it. It is not sure that the decoherence at the contact with the macroscopic apparatus, produces the collapse - see entanglements where we have more than 1 apparatus, and we can't even say at which time are the worlds generated. But it won't help, because who wants those worlds at any price would argue endlessly, and invent new and new ad-hoc arguments. So, pleasant journey in other worlds.

Comment: @Sofia: What's ad hoc about applying the equations of motion of quantum systems to everything and working out their consequences? We can make precise predictions about the expectation values of observables, and about what systems will exhibit interference and entanglement. The "worlds" are a distant and unimportant consequence of all that stuff. They are necessarily vague since some interference is always happening, e.g. - electrons in atoms. Also, since nobody has never seen a dinosaur, only dinosaur skeletons, do you reject the existence of dinosaurs?

Comment: @alanf   did you see the skeletons of those many worlds? An ad-hoc assumptions, is an assumption supported by no evidence, and only made for explaining your theory. A plausible assumption is one that also explains other experiments.

Comment: @sofia: The existence of the multiverse is entailed by the only known explanation for single particle interference, entanglement and so on, just as the existence of dinosaurs is entailed by the only known explanation of their skeletons. The MWI does not introduce ad hoc qualifications of quantum mechanics. Also support does not make sense. Any given evidence is compatible with an infinite set of theories, so it can't support any particular theory in that set. But it can refute a theory, see "Logic of Scientific Discovery" and "Realism and the Aim of Science" by Karl Popper.

Comment: @alanf  I apologize but there in so "pope" in physics. So, what Popper said is equal in rights to what any other scientist said. The skeletons of the dinosaurs were seen, they coincide in the geological époque with the époque of other huge reptiles, with other evidences of the flora and fauna of that époque, so, it's not as you say. This is why MWI is ad hoc, while the dinosaurs is not. **Moreover** the MWI is **at odds with entanglements**. So, what will we do, deny entanglements, which are an experimental fact, and retain worlds that nobody perceived by any apparatuses?

Comment: @sofia: You haven't answered the argument against support.  Do you have an answer? I was referring you to Popper to get more details than I could fit in a comment. Ad hoc means that  an idea has been made up to solve a particular problem and has no other implications. The MWI is an explanation of how the world works, not a made up solution to a single problem, unlike collapse. The MWI is not at odds with entanglement, it helps to explain entanglement, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223.

Comment: @alanf  I don't need to see what different people said about MWI. This idea falls in front of the entanglements, and in front of the conservation of matter. Creating universes means creating more matter in amounts needed to fill universes. Our universe was produced by a big bang. How are produced those universes? By an electron falling on a photographic plate? Also, how can universes become entangled? Now, I regret but I won't read 24 pages, we can discuss it in the chat room where you can tell me what the article ***told you***. I am willing to answer ***you*** not the authors of the article.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21364/discussion-between-alanf-and-sofia).

Comment: @alanf With pleasure.